# Non-orthogonal extension of an inner product

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $W$ be a real linear vector space of possibly infinite dimension and let $<\cdot, \cdot>_W$ be an *inner product* on $W$. Further let $V$ be a superspace of $W$, such that holds $V = W \bigoplus span\{\psi\}$.

I am calling an inner product $<\cdot, \cdot>_V$ an ***extension of $<\cdot, \cdot>_W$ orthogonal to $\psi$***, if it satisfies

1. $<\phi, \rho>_V = <\phi, \rho>_W \quad \forall\,\phi, \rho \in W$
2. $<\phi, \psi>_V = 0 \quad \forall\,\phi \in W$.

Any element $\phi \in V$ has a unique decomposition $\phi = \phi_w + a\cdot\psi$ with $\phi_w \in W$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Hence the mapping $$\alpha_\psi: V \to \mathbb{R}, \; (\phi_w+ a\cdot\psi) \mapsto a$$ is well defined, linear and suffices $\alpha_\psi(\phi)=0$ for all $\phi \in W$.

We can decompose any extension $<\cdot, \cdot>_V$ of $<\cdot, \cdot>_W$ orthogonal to $\psi$ as follows
$$\begin{align}
<\phi, \rho>_V &= <\phi_w, \rho_w>_W + \alpha_\psi(\phi)<\rho,\psi>_V+\alpha_\psi(\rho)<\phi,\psi>_V + \alpha_\psi(\phi)\alpha_\psi(\rho)<\psi,\psi>_V\\
&= <\phi_w, \rho_w>_W + \alpha_\psi(\phi)\alpha_\psi(\rho)<\psi, \psi>_V
\end{align}.$$
In other words: Any extension $<\cdot, \cdot>_V$ of $<\cdot, \cdot>_W$ orthogonal to $\psi$ is of the form
$$<\phi, \rho>_V = <\phi_w, \rho_w>_W + \lambda\cdot \alpha_\psi(\phi)\alpha_\psi(\rho),$$
for some $\lambda > 0$.

**My question**: Can we say anything about the existence and uniqueness of extensions of the inner product $<\cdot, \cdot>_W$ to $V$ that are **not** orthogonal to $\psi$ (i.e. suffice 1. but not 2.)?

In finite dimension uniqueness certainly does not hold (but can we say anything about the cardinality of extensions w.r.t. the dimension?) In infinitely dimensions does existence holds? And is uniqueness possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, and it is very easy: suppose $A$ is a linear operator on $V$ that is bounded away from $0$ and $\infty$, i. e. there exist constants $0 < c < C$ such that 
\begin{align*}
c \, \mathbb{1} \leq A \leq C \, \mathbb{1}
\end{align*}
holds. Note that in general $A$ mixes the subspaces $W$ and $\mathrm{span}\{ \psi \}$!

Now define a second scalar product on $V$ which is weighted by $A$, namely 
\begin{align*}
\langle \varphi \, , \, \eta \rangle_A := \bigl \langle \varphi \, , \, A \eta \bigr \rangle_V 
. 
\end{align*}
You can check that $\langle \, \cdot \, , \, \cdot \, \rangle_A$ satisfies all the axioms of a scalar product, and that the two norms induced by the scalar products $\langle \, \cdot \, , \, \cdot \, \rangle_A$ and $\langle \, \cdot \, , \, \cdot \, \rangle_V$ are equivalent. Thus, you obtain a *second* Hilbert space $V_A$ that agrees with $V$ as Banach spaces. That means that $A$ is still a bounded operator on $V_A$ that is bounded away from $0$ and $\infty$ (with different constants).

Then *unless* $A$ is block-diagonal with respect to the direct sum decomposition $V = W \oplus \mathrm{span} \{ \psi \} = V_A$ (the latter equality is the equality as Banach spaces!), the two subspaces $V_A$ (i. e. $V$ equipped with the alternative scalar product) are no longer orthogonal to each other. These arguments also work if you tack on an $N$- or infinite-dimensional subspace rather than a $1$-dimensional one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! In order to satisfy condition 1. form above, the operator $A$ needs to leave $W$ invariant. So that the question that still remains for me is of the existence of an operator $A$ that is not block diagonal and leaves $W$ invariant... which I now realised is obviously true ... Thanks!

Comment: Is it really obvious that there exists a non-block diagonal operator on $V$ that leaves $W$ invariant and is bounded away from zero and infinity?

Comment: The way I read your definition is that you need to satisfy *both* conditions in order to have an orthogonal extension (you claim that being not orthogonal still means (1) has to be satisfied, but I disagree, mathematically you need both conditions!). Even if you drop only condition (1), the extension is not unique: in that case $A = \mathbb{1} \oplus B$ where $B$ is a linear operator on the subspace you tack on that is bounded away from $0$ and $\infty$. If you add a one-dimensional subspace, $B = \lambda$ is just a positive real number $\lambda > 0$. So your extension is not unique.

Comment: But I'm searching for a scalar product that suffices: (1) & ¬(2). This can't really be mathematically incorrect, since the answer to that question can be: yes there exists such a product, or no there does not. The example you gave is an example of an orthogonal extension, just like the one I characterised in my question. (I mean the example in the comment above this one, not the general one of your answer).

Comment: You asked whether an extension exists (yes) and is unique (no). This is even the case if you require (1) *and* (2) to hold, e. g. $A = \mathbb{1} \oplus \lambda$ where $\lambda > 0$. This is still correct if you drop condition (2): condition (1) does *not* imply that the offdiagonal part of $A$ vanishes. Take the case where $W = \mathbb{C}$ so that $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix. (1) is then satisfied iff $A_{11} = (1,0)^T \cdot A (1,0)^T$ equals $1$. Thus, (1) does not impose any restrictions on the other entries of $A$, including the offdiagonal ones. Also here, the extension is not unique.

Comment: But A has another condition to satisfy: positive definiteness. I agree and also wrote so in my question above that in the finite dimensional case uniqueness does not hold. I personally wondered whether in the infinite dimensional case that changes. By now nothing convinced me to lay of that conjecture. And note also that I’m not dropping condition (2), much more I’m imposing the condition not(2). A big difference. In that way the absence of uniqueness for products that satisfy (2) does not necessarily implies something about the case were not(2) is sufficed.

Comment: $A = \left ( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 \\ \end{matrix} \right )$ is a symmetric (and hermitian) matrix with eigenvalues $2 \pm \sqrt{2} > 0$ — and therefore positive definite. Because $A$ has a non-zero diagonal, condition (2) is violated, eg $(1,0)^T \cdot A (0,1) = 1 \neq 0$. This extends immediately to higher (including infinite) dimensions: pick a one-dimensional subspace $W_0$ of $W$ and use the matrix $A$ above to mix states from this subspace with the extra space you tack on. One choice is then that $W_0^{\perp} \subset W$ you extend $A$ by the identity.